Stable Diffusion Using CPU Instead of GPU - Performance Issues
I recently acquired an Nvidia (RTX 4090) device to improve the performance of Stable Diffusion. However, despite having a compatible GPU, Stable Diffusion seems to be using the CPU instead, leading to significantly slower performance.
It completes an 18-second video in 1 hour using mov2mov and reactor. I selected NV from SD settings stable diffusion settings but nothing changed.
What should I do to increase performance, can you help?
